# Box with scroll bar appears over Like button in IE9

Tags: html, xcode, facebook-like

I added a Like button to a friend's website.  In all browsers (IE7-8-9, Firefox 6, Chrome), if a visitor is logged into their FB account, a box with a scroll bar appears next to the Like button and remains visible.  It's hard to see what is in the box, but it appears to be my own Facebook page.  Can this box be removed or a setting changed so it doesn't show?

Answer (score 1):

The login button actually has a different state when you're logged in. I'm going to assume that you've set the size of the button div via CSS. If you've done that, then you'll get that effect. Play with the width/height values of the container.